# How to remove undo from history (RevertAllInCurrentGroup?)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use `RevertAllInCurrentGroup` to undo the last operation but it doesn't seem to work. Actually what I really want to do is just remove the undo from the history; I don't care whether the undo is applied or not.

In some init code I have:

```
// 'component' is a MonoBehaviour-derived class. Here I create the default editor for the component
m_editor = Editor.CreateEditor(component);
```

And then in `OnGUI` in my `EditorWindow`:

```
m_editor.OnInspectorGUI();
// ..'hasChanged' is set to true if the user changed some property
if (hasChanged)
{
    // ..do some stuff using the new values on the object, which includes sending a message to a server
    Undo.RevertAllInCurrentGroup();
}
```

When I call `RevertAllInCurrentGroup` I get `InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object` in some `Stack` object in `GUILayoutUtility.EndLayoutGroup`. I figured maybe I shouldn't be doing the revert in `OnGUI`, so I changed it to set a flag and do the revert in `Update` but that doesn't make any difference (except I obviously no longer get the exception).

Does anyone know how to use this function, or if there is some other way that I could undo the last operation that was applied by the `Editor` instance? I've tried using `Undo.RegisterCompleteObjectUndo` and `Undo.ClearUndo` but they don't seem to do anything either (the undo operation still appears in the undo stack).

For clarification, I'm dynamically creating `GameObjects` with components in the editor based on messages I receive from a server (which is a running Unity game, which could be inside or outside the editor - this is a live update system). Then I allow editing of those components, and send the changed components back to the server. I'm rendering my own inspector UI and I wanted to use the built-in `Editor` instances for components (e.g. so the built-in `CameraEditor` will be used if there is a `Camera` component).

The only problem is that using the built-in editors causes undo operations to be added to the stack, but I really don't care about these undo operations because the `GameObject` they apply to is just a temporary placeholder `GameObject` which is continually updated every coulpe of seconds, whenever I receive a new message from the server.

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is the same as clicking on the Edit->Undo menu (or as you put, undo the last operation that was applied by the editor), use below code:

```
Undo.PerformUndo();
```

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right, I could just use that! What i mean though is I'd like to undo the last operation applied by the `Editor` instance that I was using (or undo/remove all undo history for the object that I'm currently editing). Anyway I'll keep this open for now in case anyone else has any other suggestions.

Comment: Actually this is no good because it doesn't remove the operation from the undo stack. I can still "redo" the operation. I need it removed entirely from the undo stack.